# Assigning image to Post-Type won't work anymore: exceeded time?

Tags: images, uploads

weird, but for some reason i get suddenly the following error in my Wordpress backend when assigning an image from the "media-gallery" to a post-type.

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 80 seconds exceeded in /home/.sites/85/site2556/web/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor-gd.php on line 182

-> http://cloud.florianmatthias.com/ZMHn

The image was uploaded successfully, i just can't assign it to the post. The image is only 560x560px in size.

I deactivated all plugins but didn't make a difference.

kind regards

Comment: I think you should modify your php.ini file and set : ini_set('max_execution_time', 150); , Save file and then try to upload image.

Answer (score 0):

Please set maximum execution time like below :

1 - Modify your php.ini file and set  **ini_set('max_execution_time', 150);**

OR

2 - Modify your site root .htaccess file and set **php_value max_execution_time 150**

Note : you can extend it as per your need. Here 150 means 2.5 minutes.